# How to get state of CPU registers in python?

Tags: python, cpu-registers

Is there any possibility to obtain state of registers inside processor? For example: which combination of bits are occupying AX, BX registers?

Obviously assembler got the access to these informations, but can do it python?

Comment: The state of the registers when? Python is an interpreted high-level language, so the state of the registers is constantly being changed by the interpreter itself, and only very indirectly by the Python code currently being executed—so your question doesn't make much sense as it stands, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Python is a high-level language, machine-level stuff is abstracted away so there is no means to directly access the state of registers in the the CPU. I'm not aware of any means of doing this without writing the assembly code to access the required values.

***Approach 1: Hack it!***

Can you write the assembler code yourself?

The [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) library provides C compatible data types, and allows calling functions in DLLs or shared libraries.

```
import ctypes
import sys
import os

# PROT_xxxx constants
PROT_NONE = 0x0
PROT_READ = 0x1
PROT_WRITE = 0x2
PROT_EXEC = 0x4

# Get the system page size
pagesize = os.sysconf('SC_PAGESIZE')
# Get a handle on the standard C library
libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')
# You need to build your assembler code string
asm = "HEX CODES GO IN HERE"
# Create a string buffer with the assembler
buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(asm)
# Get the address of the buffer
buff_addr = ctypes.addressof(buff)
buff_addr_rounded = (buff_addr / pagesize) * pagesize
# Mark the memory executable
result = libc.mprotect(buff_addr_rounded, 1*pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC)
# Turn the buffer contents into a callable function
f = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(buff_addr)
# Call the function and pray that it doesn't explode!
f()
```

The issue with this approach is you need to get write the code to be executed in the buffer yourself. To do this you will probably write the code in as inline assembler in a simple C program and disassemble the executable to find exactly what hex codes you need to put in the buffer.

***Approach 2: Write a (C) extension for Python***

You can [inline assembler in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_assembler) so you could follow the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/) to create an extension.

***Approach 3: Use a library that can compile the assembly code***

[PyCCA](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycca) can compile and execute the assembly code for you at runtime.

Comment: Note that none of these approaches actually do anything useful, since the mere act of calling the C/assembly code is almost certainly going to change the register you're interested in.  It's like asking a person what they're thinking about right now - the only true answer would be "I'm thinking about answering your question".